# Syntax Error in From clause Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

```
 public void SetConnection(string text1, string text2, string text3, string text4, string text5, string text6, string text7)
    {


        connectionString1 = "Initial Catalog=testdb; Data Source=work\\sqlexpress";




        database = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\Users\\test.xls';Extended Properties= \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");
        database.Open();
        database1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" + connectionString1);
        database1.Open();
    }

data1 = DataAccess.DatabaseTables("SELECT * from [Sheet1$])", DataAccess.database); 

 public DataTable DatabaseTables(string QueryString, OleDbConnection DataConnection)
    {

        OleDbCommand SQLQuery = new OleDbCommand();
        DataTable data = null;
        SQLQuery.Connection = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
        SQLQuery.CommandText = QueryString;
        SQLQuery.Connection = DataConnection;
        data = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery);

        dataAdapter.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }
```

I am getting  exception "Syntax error in from clause" for the line of code starting at data1. This line calls the function below it DatabaseTables which generates this exception.
I have also included the connection string which uses jet etc in the fn SetConnection. I think the problem could be the connection string itself. Currently i have to leave the excel file open to prevent a "could not decrypt" error. I did try the ACE driver but got errors. The excel work book is saved as a 97-03 workbook.

Comment: Is your sheet named as `Sheet1`?

Comment: Yes the sheet is Sheet1

Comment: `(`"SELECT * from [Sheet1$]`)`", DataAccess.database `)` ;there is one bracket missing,see the highlighted one.

Comment: Yes you are right. My query was "SELECT * from [Sheet1$])" ; it should be "SELECT * from [Sheet1$]" !. I am really sorry for wasting people's time on this.

Comment: if it solves your problem then don't forget to accept as a answer.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
data1 = DataAccess.DatabaseTables("SELECT * from [Sheet1$])", DataAccess.database);
```

with

```
data1 = DataAccess.DatabaseTables("SELECT * from [Sheet1$]", DataAccess.database);
```

There is one extra closing bracket.

Hope it works.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I think i will take a five minute walk of fresh air.